# Effect of the BRICK permission on Android

Tags: android, security

There is a permission called `BRICK` on Android phones. It seems that you need the platform key to actually use it, so regular apps cannot take advantage of it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238819/when-would-one-use-the-brick-permission) post from 2011 for more information.

When installing from AOPS I believe we can change the release keys, including the platform key (other being shared, media, testkey). This means we would then be able to use the `BRICK` permission.

1. What would this permission actually do?
2. Is this some sort of soft brick from which we can recover from, or does it actually burn some kind of one-time programmable (OTP) bit on the device preventing any further use?

Comment: i bet this is related http://www.nbcnews.com/tech/mobile/smartphone-kill-switch-senators-propose-federal-anti-theft-bill-n30366

Comment: Samsung currently has that functionality with the `Find My Mobile` service. It enables the device owner to make a stolen/lost device ring at the highest sound, lock the device or wipe the user data, among other features. This is done remotely from a website.

Answer (score 0):

> Required to be able to disable the device (very dangerous!).

[Link to documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BRICK)

Edit: There is already a thread about the BRICK permission: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238819/when-would-one-use-the-brick-permission)